# Move field to a specific object in an array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Here's my data:

```
{
  foos: [
    { _id: 1 },
    { _id: 2 },
    { _id: 3 }
  ],
  bar: "baz"
}
```

Now I wanna move field `bar` into `foos` object with `_id = 2` to have this:

```
{
  foos: [
    { _id: 1 },
    { _id: 2, bar: "baz" },
    { _id: 3 },
  ]
}
```

How can I do this using aggregation framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `$map` to iterate loop of `foos` and check `_id: 2` condition, if match then return `bar` object and merge with current object `$mergeObjects`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      foos: {
        $map: {
          input: "$foos",
          in: {
            $cond: [
              { $eq: ["$$this._id", 2] },
              { $mergeObjects: ["$$this", { bar: "$bar" }] },
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nDSeBpWGNgj)